# Display Rails error messages inside a Bootstrap modal when using Selectize and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to build an app that allows users to share quotes by artists about other artists. For instance, a quote by Bob Dylan about John Lennon. As such, my Artist model is set up in a way that allows an artist to be both the Speaker and Topic on a Quote, and each Quote belongs_to each Artist as the Speaker or Topic.

I'm having trouble getting a Rails error message to display inside a Bootstrap modal when using Selectize to trigger the modal. I got the modal working by following [this demo](https://gorails.com/episodes/select-or-create-with-selectize-js).

The modal is used to create a new `Artist` from the `quotes/new` form, but I can't get the error messages for the `Artist` model to display in the Bootstrap modal or on the quotes/new page. When I try to create something that triggers an error message (such as validates_uniqueness) in the modal, it just closes the modal and doesn't display the error message. Everything else is working as expected.

What am I missing to connect the Ajax request to the view?

Here's the relevant section of my form:

```
<%= f.label :speaker, 'Who said it?' %>
<%= f.collection_select :speaker_id, @speakers, :id, :name,
{prompt: 'Select an artist'}, {class: 'form-control selectize-speaker'} %>
```

Full source for [quotes/form.html.erb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/3bbe331b28cf91c0f81dcf92cc3e435b)

Here's the relevant code in my controller:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @artist = current_user.artists.build(artist_params)
    authorize @artist

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artist.save
        if request.referer.include?("artists")
          flash[:success] = "Artist was successfully created."
          format.html { redirect_to @artist }
        else
          format.json { render json: @artist }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @artist.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Full source for [artists_controller.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/3440a860ee1fc5f1969fac8b9a9d8f60)

Relevant javascript code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  var selectizeCallback = null;

  // Selectize Speaker
  $('.speaker-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    if (selectizeCallback != null) {
      selectizeCallback();
      selecitzeCallback = null;
    }

    $('#new_speaker').trigger('reset');
  });

  $('#new_speaker').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        selectizeCallback({value: response.id, text: response.name});
        selectizeCallback = null;

        $('.speaker-modal').modal('toggle');
      }
    });
  });

  $('.selectize-speaker').selectize({
    create: function(input, callback) {
      selectizeCallback = callback;

      $('.speaker-modal').modal();
      $('#speaker_name').val(input);
    }
  }); // end selectize speaker
}); // end document on
```

Full source for [quotes.js](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/6d824bc51783f984904c8790c61c032f).

And my error message partial, shared/_error_messages.html.erb:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id='error_explanation'>
     <div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
        <p><strong>The form contains
          <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, 'error') %>.</strong></p>
        <ul>
           <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
           <% end %>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Additional source files:

[models/quote.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/4547b85c3252f9a5ee420d70734c2a14)

[models/artist.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/478ead0cbc7703d5bdabfd44b288fb44)

[controllers/quotes_controller.rb](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/c1a11804ed019606d42cc9d3b52ca7e4)

Comment: when toggling, `$('.speaker-modal').modal('toggle')` are you trying to close or open a model ? Also yr requesting as JSON, so errors will be responded as JSON also.

Comment: @7urkm3n `$('.speaker-modal').modal('toggle')` closes the modal after the POST request creates the Artist. Do I simply need to embed the JSON in the view before the toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Both a successful and unsuccessful save are returning a `200` response, which means that your `success` callback will be called:

```
  success: function(response) {
    selectizeCallback({value: response.id, text: response.name});
    selectizeCallback = null;

    $('.speaker-modal').modal('toggle');
  }
```

This always toggles the modal, therefore closing it.

If you ensure that the response is a `4xx` on validation error, then you can define an `error` callback which populates your errors list and does **not** close the modal.

So instead of:

```
format.json { render json: @artist.errors.full_messages }
```

Use something like:

```
format.json { render json: @artist.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request }
```

Then, pass an `error` callback to your AJAX call:

```
error: function(response) {
  // somehow populate your errors list
  // display the errors list
}
```

This won't work right now, though, because the errors container won't exist: you only render it under this condition:

```
object.errors.any?
```

Which, on initial load, will always evaluate false. What you can instead do is always render the errors container, default it to some hidden class if there aren't any errors, and in your `error` callback, remove the hidden class after it's populated.